# Collaborate to answer

Tags: discussion, answers

**Question:** If the question is about proving $P$, which, pointed out in comments, follows from $Q$ and $R$. Is it acceptable to write an answer only containing the proof of $Q$, as part of collaboration?

This is what I have encountered in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338464/an-upper-bound-on-the-minimum-number-of-vertices-in-a-girth-5-graph-of-chromatic). I proposed a random graph model, and what remains is to show that

- $Q$: It has girth 5, and
- $R$: It has unbounded chromatic number.

I can prove the graph has girth 5 with high probablity under my model, but I'm not sure whether they have unbounded chromatic number. Maybe someone can prove $R$, and it would complete the answer.

Comment: Even though the post type is "answer" , I and many others have used that type to post information about the/an answer, and sometimes this is labelled as a "non-answer" or partial answer.  If the intent is to make progress toward an answer or inform others that the problem is hard, it is good to share information to that effect. Is there another issue with your example that concerns you?  Gerhard "Wonders Where The Difficulty Is" Paseman, 2019.08.17.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman Suppose there is an answer for $Q$ and another answer for $R$. Which answer should be accepted? Or maybe they should be written in a single answer?

Comment: I have written summaries and accepted them for questions, including my first question (31337). If you are concerned about reputation, consider awarding two or more bounties. In any case, you can edit the question to offer acknowledgements and thanks apart from the voting/accepting system.  Gerhard "Right Words Can Heal Much" Paseman, 2019.08.17.